# How to get the signal strength of the network connected with the ESP8266

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I am using ESP8266 module with Arduino Uno.I don't know how to get the signal strength of the network with which ESP8266 is connected.Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page http://tomeko.net/other/ESP8266/ names the following command:

> AT+CWLAP     // list available access points

According to the example given there, this returns a list of items looking like this:

> +CWLAP:(3,"UPC784xxx",-75,"70:54:d2:xx:xx:xx",1)

where *"APs are sorted by channel and values are: (security, "name", **signal strength**, MAC, channel) where for security: 0 = open, 1 = WEP, 3 = WPA, 4 = WPA2"*.

Thus you can use `AT+CWJAP?` to obtain the name of the network you're connected to and get the signal strength from the respective item in the list provided by `AT+CWLAP`.

See http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/ESP8266_Serial_WIFI_Module for a reference of commands.

Comment: The security is wrong. Correct are (according to the documentation 0.2 from March 20, 2015): 0 = open, 1 = WEP, 2 = WPA_PSK, 3 = WPA2_PSK, 4 = WPA_WPA2_PSK.